# Data recovery in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, dell, data-recovery, data-loss

I have Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted with windows 8. While I was using Ubuntu, all of a sudden my system went into a suspend mode and when I logged back in all my data was gone. It was Ubuntu in its pristine form. Though some applications like Pidgin, File Zilla, Google Chrome, Xsensors etc. still continue to work. Windows, on the other hand, is working perfectly fine. How can I recover my data? I need my data badly!

Comment: What data are you missing? What have your tired ? See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am missing all my data from ubuntu(ext 4). As of now I haven't tried anything as I didn't want to do anything wrong. I went through that page but I didn't find a case similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while dual booting with Windows 7.

A slow but effective process in my case was to use PhotoRec http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec (it recovers most file types, not just pictures).

Good luck!

Comment: Is it normal for it to take 35hours for recovery?

Comment: @ArchitVerma - depends on the size of your hard drive, but sounds a little longer then I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) can help you. Basically you need to run the live CD/DVD which you used when you installed Ubuntu, and after you boot into the live session you need to install one or more data recovery programs in a terminal or with Synaptic Package Manager, The programs are **testdisk**, **scalpel** and/or **foremost**. Code:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk scalpel foremost
```

Use the detailed instructions from the provided link to learn how to recover your lost/deleted data.